# Setting margins using geometry package

Tags: geometry

How can I change the four margins differently using the geometry package ?

Currently I have got

```
{\geometry{
   paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=21cm
   textwidth=20cm,  textheight=20cm}}
```

Comment: Remove the outer braces around your `\geometry` setting. If this doesn't solve your problem, please provide more detail.

Comment: By "change the four margins differently", do you mean wanting to set asymmetric margins? Please advise.

Comment: Also, note that there are two different meanings for the word `margins`. One meaning: Header and footer sit within the top and bottom margin areas, and text in the side margins is also possible.. Other meaning: Nothing sits within the margin areas, because nothing may be printed there. The `geometry` package documentation has a diagram.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: Have looked at it but found it overwhelming, so many settings and variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instruction

```
\geometry{ paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=21cm,
           textwidth=20cm,  textheight=20cm}
```

can also be expressed as

```
\geometry{ paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=21cm, margin=5mm }
```

To set *asymmetric* vertical and/or horizontal margins, you could run, say,

```
\geometry{ paperwidth=21cm, paperheight=21cm, 
           left=3mm, right=7mm, top=4mm, bottom=6mm }
```

Comment: Note that the effect of top and bottom change with noheadfoot.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Thanks. I'm still hoping the OP will clarify what, precisely, is meant by "change the four margins differently".

Comment: Correct, applying asymmetric margins.